# Exclusão da Conta

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Queria remover a minha conta, já mandei um e-mail pro site avisando sobre a exclusão da conta e ainda não aconteceu, também coloquei o "por favor, excluam-me" no meu perfil, para quem sabe um moderador ou adm veja, mas nada acontece. 
Queria remover a conta o mais rápido possível.
Simplesmente não exclui, tempo d 23 horas não acaba, ele incremente após um tempo de 30 minutos, ou menos até as 23., esperei o tempo acabar, os 30 minutos mas ele não acaba. Então criei outra conta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] E

Comment: Se você já mandou o email, precisa aguardar. Os administradores do site irão avaliar sua solicitação e encaminhar a exclusão da conta.

Comment: Confirmando, você contatou os admins pelo [formulário de contato do site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/contact)? Precisa ser por lá.

Comment: Isso mesmo, foi por esse link.

Comment: Eles não estão acusando o recebimento de nenhuma mensagem sua (ou o assunto seria outra conta?). Por favor preencha o formulário novamente

Comment: Enviei novamente.

Comment: Isso demora?? http://prntscr.com/7599kl

Comment: Não sei, está fora do meu controle. Eu sou quase como um usuário comum, moderadores são voluntários. Esses emails são tratados pela equipe de Comunidade da Stack Exchange.

Comment: Eu havia enviado a solicitação de exclusão ontem.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Excluir vinculo com uma "comunidade" especifica](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2306/excluir-vinculo-com-uma-comunidade-especifica)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, é a exclusão total, não uma comunidade específica.

Comment: Faz sentido, acredito que possa ser o mesmo caminho, não tenho certeza.

Comment: @user24857 posso estar enganado mas você não tem uma conta no SOpt pois seu usuário não é definido (seu login: user24857) tente excluir o histórico de navegação.

Comment: Ricardo Henrique, não lhe entendi, tenho uma conta sim.

Comment: É porque quando não se tem uma conta geralmente seu `nick` fica parecido com o seu (user+numeros), mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique, já alterei o nome, mas não consigo excluir.

Answer (score 2):

Como podem perceber, a conta acabou excluída. Estou passando o assunto para o Gabe verificar com os desenvolvedores se o comportamento que vimos no screenshot é intencional, ou se é algum bug.